# Changing the symbols shown in a HTML password field

Tags: html, input, passwords

Is there any way to change the asterisks (`*`), or in some browsers a bullet (`•`), that appears in password fields in HTML?

Comment: See https://github.com/Mottie/input-password-bullet

Answer (score 52, accepted):

You can't change the password masking character in the standard password field. You can fake it with a textbox, but it makes for a weak security model because you don't get the protection you do from the password textbox. As a side note, it's generally not a good idea to change the behaviour of items like this because users have become used to one form of masking, and you will be introducing a different one - if there's no good reason to do this, I'd avoid it.

Comment: How can I fake it with textbox, however I am not using this feature for password, please check the question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31604402/replace-text-with-stars-in-html-without-javascript?noredirect=1#comment51159417_31604402

Comment: What protection do you exactly get from a password field? For all I know it's just another element that's easily changeable with devtools. There's no security at all surrounding a password field except for the browser autofilling the fields with saved credentials. Am I missing something?

Comment: @GuidoVisser You right. Besides that sometimes I don't want to show saved passwords and no way to disable it for all major browsers.

Answer (score 64):

Create your own font and use `@font-face` and `font-family` (and `font-size`) for `input[type="password"]`. It should help to solve your problem. But... you must create font with replaced bullet and asterisk character. All character numbers in font may represent the same character. Use google to find free program to edit vector fonts.

**Never say "it is impossible".** You should find a hack for your problem.

Characters to be replaced with your symbol (for Chrome, Firefox and MSIE):
26AB, 25E6, 25CF, 25D8, 25D9, 2219, 20F0, 2022, 2024, 00B7, 002A.

(18C)

Comment: Do you have an example font to share?

Comment: this should be the perfect answer... Thanks man... solved my problem

Comment: @waLLe: Woman not man... People rarely think abstract and multilevel behaviour. BTW. the question is old (2009) but still active. In the past the `@font-face` was not defined. In 2009 it was not possible but... people repeat the answer despite the fact Firefox supports it from v3.5, IE probably from v6, Chrome from v4. But still... Opera Mini doesn't support. When I wrote my answer, the main answer has +21 points.

Comment: @18C .. Hey Ms, sex can't be guessed by your id 18c.Using balance of probability, I said "man"... Sorry about that.. Anyway, thanks for the explanation.. :)

Comment: @waLLe: then use universal and natural "you". It is OK in english language.

Comment: @18C ok :))))))

Comment: This sounds really good, Can any one please share a possible tutorial reference for this!

Comment: @BlackBurn027 There is needed only `@font-face` etc. in CSS (read about it), font-forge application for edition/creation of fonts. In font-forge you can copy (Ctrl+C) characters and replace other (Ctrl+V). You also can provide your own mask character. If editinf fonts, use MIT licensed fonts (for example Liberation). Do not edit Helvetica or Arial (due to license problems).

Comment: Worked for me!! I used FontForge: https://fontforge.org/en-US/downloads/windows-dl/. The character I had to change was U+2022. I modified a copy of the Arial font face that I downloaded from my system. You can search for the Unicode character in FontForge via "View > Goto".

Answer (score 10):

I know that is a very old question, but I faced this problem today, and I solved it using this approach: https://github.com/Mottie/input-password-bullet

Basically, I created a new font where assign the default point, to another icon. Then, only need to import the font files to the project and add a css similar to this:

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: 'fontello';
    src: url('/fonts/fontello.eot');
    src: url('/fonts/fontello.eot') format('embedded-opentype'),
    url('/fonts/fontello.woff') format('woff'),
    url('/fonts/fontello.ttf') format('truetype'),
    url('/fonts/fontello.svg') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;
}

input[type="password"] {
    font-family: "fontello";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    speak: none;
    color: red;
    font-size: 16px;

    /* For safety - reset parent styles, that can break glyph codes*/
    font-variant: normal;
    text-transform: none;

    /* Font smoothing. That was taken from TWBS */
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
    /* Uncomment for 3D effect */
    /* text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(127, 127, 127, 0.3); */

    /* add spacing to better separate each image */
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: It was very helpful!

Comment: For Angular users: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45956661/adding-fontello-in-angular-cli

Answer (score 9):

As of now, it appears as though this is possible in webkit browsers. Please see http://help.dottoro.com/lcbkewgt.php for examples and documentation.

**Does not apply to password input**

```html
<input type="text" style="-webkit-text-security: square;" />
```

There is no good solution for other browsers as of when this answer was written and even in webkit browsers, the characters you are allowed to specify are very limited.

Comment: This doesn't work. I tested it on 4 different browsers.

Comment: Updated. Thank you @OleHaugset .

Answer (score 5):

No - the user agent chooses its own default style, and there is (to my knowledge) no CSS attributes you can change to determine the masking character.

Of course, this would be possible if the password field was just a standard text field, and you manually masked the input with a javascript event handler (onKeyPress, probably).  You could even declare the field as `type="password"` in the HTML, then have your JS function modify the DOM to change its type.  I'd be a little wary about doing this, though; the browser implementation is almost certainly pretty solid, and circumventing established security functionality to roll your own is rarely a good idea.

Comment: Established security functionality? Password and text input fields in HTML are about the same, just the UI changes, with the masking happening in password fields.
I'm not downvoting your answer, but this is not like reinventing the wheel or creating a homebrew crypto engine, it's just patching a UI element to your meet your likes.

Comment: @Spidey, besides character masking, password fields also prevent copying content from them, depending on the browser and operating system.

Comment: @MicahHenning Thank you for pointing this out. Anyway, even if the user tried copying from the custom textbox, all he would get would be asteriscs or points or any other symbol you choose to mask the real password.

Answer (score 4):

```html
<input type="text" style="-webkit-text-security: circle;" />
```

Comment: The CSS property `-webkit-text-security` will not work on IE, Firefox, or Opera.

Comment: Also this property does not support arbitrary characters; it only offers you four optkons along the lines of circle and square.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like I'm pretty late, but another potential solution is below for any looking for a workaroud. The only **"bug"** I didn't bother to look into was that you can't highlight and delete everyhting at once. Other than that, it works as intended, the user can input their password and they will see a string of whatever you want (in this example, a star) and their recently pressed key.

```js
//window.onload = () => {
//  sessionStorage.text = "";
//  sessionStorage.visible = false
//}

//We will use the text and visible variables for demonstration purposes as session storage does not work with code snippets. The star can really be anything you want

const star = "*";
let text = "";
let isVisible = false;

function toggle(id) {
  const button = document.getElementById(id);
  const input = document.getElementById("password-input");
  
  switch (isVisible) {
    case false:
      button.innerText = "Hide Password";
      input.value = text;
      isVisible = true;
      break;
    case true:
      button.innerText = "Show Password";
      input.value = star.repeat(text.length);
      isVisible = false;
  }
  
  console.log(`Text When Button Clicked: ${text}`);
}

function formatInput(id) {
  //The tl:dr of this is that each key pressed (so long as it's valid which is to be determined by you) will be added to session storag which you can call from anywhere, allowing you to register stars of the correct length or text of the correct value
  
  const elem = document.getElementById(id);
  const keyPressed = event.key;
 
 //event.key should be equal to 1 unless you want it to register "Backspace" and so on as inputs. The elem.value change in the first conditional is necessary to avoid removing more than 1 character on the input; Wihtout it, we would get something like text.length = x and elem.value.length = x - 1
 
  if (keyPressed == "Backspace") {
    text = text.substring(0, text.length - 1);
    elem.value = elem.value.substring(0, elem.value.length);
    console.log(`Text at Backspace: ${text}`)
    return;
  }
  
  if (keyPressed.length == 1) {
    text = text + keyPressed;
    elem.value = text;
  }
  
  //You could use a conditional here, I just prefer switches in the case that we are checking one simple thing
  
  switch (isVisible) {
    case false:
      elem.value = star.repeat(text.length - 1)
      console.log(`Text When Password = Hidden: ${text}`)
            break;
    case true:
      elem.value = text;
      //This is required as wihtout it there is a bug that duplicated the first entry if someone decides to show the password
      elem.value = elem.value.substring(0, text.length - 1)
      console.log(`Text When Password = Visible: ${text}`)
  }
}
```

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}
input {
  width: 50%;
  height: 35px;
  border: 0px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2) inset;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  outline: none;
}
input:focus {
  border: 1px green solid;
}
button {
  height: 35px;
  background-color: rgb(94, 124, 153);
  border-radius: 5px;
  border: 0px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 30%;
  margin-top: 30px;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div>

<input type="text" id="password-input" placeholder="Password" onkeydown="formatInput(this.id)" value="">

<button id="toggle-button" onclick="toggle(this.id)">Show Passowrd</button>

</div>
```

Comment: I believe the browser *may* write non password fields unencrypted to disk.  This enables features like restoration after crash and restoring values when reopening a tab. At the very least, you should disable autocomplete so the browser doesn't happily give your password out to every site on the internet.

Comment: There is also an issue with the code that you can't backspace or delete any input :D And what Micah says, there are probably lots of other reasons why you want to use the type 'password'