# Styling Password Fields in CSS

Tags: css, forms, input, fonts, stylesheet

I'm experiencing a minor issue with fonts in my stylesheet.

This is my CSS:

```
body
{
  ...
  font: normal 62.5% "Lucida Sans Unicode",sans-serif;
}

#wrapper_page
{
  ...
  font-size: 1.2em;
}

input, select, textarea
{
  ...
  font: bold 100% "Lucida Sans Unicode",sans-serif;
}
```

And this is the result:

[image: browser password fields]

I think there is an internal css setting, somewhere, on webkits  that modify the shape of the password dots. How can I get rid of it and have the same style on every browser?

Thanks!

EDIT: I just found something curious: by default, webkit browsers apply this CSS to password fields:

```
input[type="password"]
{
  -webkit-text-security: disc;
}
```

And that's what is replacing the classic middot.
I tried setting it to circle or none, but I cannot get something similar to what is shown by other browsers.

EDIT: I FOUND A SOLUTION.
If you are using "Lucida Sans Unicode" font for your website, that's the problem! The only font that emulate correctly the password field's big dots of other browsers is Verdana, mixed with a little bit of letter spacing. So, for both Opera and Webkit, use the following code to fix it:

```
.opera input[type="password"],
.webkit input[type="password"]
{
  font: large Verdana,sans-serif;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
 }
```

Comment: that just uses a plain text input box.

Comment: Did you bother reading the other comments, Ehtesham?

Comment: No, I'm not using any kind of CSS reset. This is a simple input: body -> #wrapper_page -> <input id="password" type="password"/>

Comment: I tried using the YUI reset, but it's not changing this minor issue.

Comment: Please don't post the solution in the question and edit the title with a silly tag. Post it as an answer and mark it accepted. That's how it works here on a Q&A site :)

Comment: Here is a fiddle for you crazy diamonds...http://jsfiddle.net/x5CCf/459/

Comment: Man that was so annoying lol! Just encountered the same problem, setting the font to Verdana works perfect cheers!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the symbols shown in a HTML password field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648665/changing-the-symbols-shown-in-a-html-password-field)

Answer (score 45, accepted):

The best I can find is to set `input[type="password"] {font:small-caption;font-size:16px}`

**Demo:**

```css
input {
  font: small-caption;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<input type="password">
```

Comment: @Zarathos you can use anything you find better. The truth is that from the moment that characters are hidden there is no big difference.

Answer (score 21):

When I needed to create similar dots in input[password] I use a custom font in base64 (with 2 glyphs see above 25CF and 2022)

**After that, I got identical display input[password]**

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'pass';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(data:application/font-woff;charset=utf-8;base64,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) format('woff');
}

input[type=password]:not(:placeholder-shown) {
  font-family: 'pass', 'Roboto', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <input type="password" placeholder="Your password" />
  <br>
  <br>
  <input type="password" placeholder="Repeat password" />
</form>
```

Comment: Nice solution! In addition you can select only the "dots" version of the password input by `input[type=password]:not(:placeholder-shown)` selector. Sometimes there is no need to touch placeholders

Answer (score 16):

The problem is that (as of 2016), for the password field, Firefox and Internet Explorer use the character "Black Circle" (●), which uses the Unicode code point `25CF`, but Chrome uses the character "Bullet" (•), which uses the Unicode code point `2022`.

As you can see, even in the StackOverflow font the two characters have different sizes.

The font you're using, "Lucida Sans Unicode", has an even greater disparity between the sizes of these two characters, leading to you noticing the difference.

The simple solution is to use a font in which both characters have similar sizes.

The fix could thus be to use a default font of the browser, which should render the characters in the password field just fine:

```
input[type="password"] {
    font-family: caption;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I found I could improve the situation a little with CSS dedicated to Webkit (Safari, Chrome). However, I had to set a fixed width and height on the field because the font change will resize the field.

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0){ /* START WEBKIT */
  INPUT[type="password"]{
  font-family:Verdana,sans-serif;
  height:28px;
  font-size:19px;
  width:223px;
  padding:5px;
  }
} /* END WEBKIT */
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 0) and (min-resolution: 
0.001dpcm) {    
.chrome {
property: value;
}
.register-password input[type="password"]:not(:placeholder-shown) {
font-family: "pass";
font-size: 30px;
 }
}

@-moz-document url-prefix() {
.register-password input[type="password"]:not(:placeholder-shown) {
font-family: "pass";
font-size: 18px;
 }
}
```

This worked for me to get the same size on the password dots in firefox developer edition and chrome.