# font size different for password text box in webkit and firefox browser

Tags: html, webkit, cross-browser, passwords, font-size

I am using the password input text box to get the password from the user, and the font size of the dots coming while type the password is different in webkit browsers and firefox(and IE).

I am using the relative font size of 1.2em(12px it should come,see in the code i attached) for the input tag, this 12px is working well in IE and firefox but not working in webkit browsers safari and chrome.

Thanks in advance for any help.

HTML Code

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en">
<head>
    <title>TEST</title>
    <meta name="Description" content="" />
    <meta name="Keywords" content="" />
    <meta name="robots" content="" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="imagetoolbar" content="no" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=EmulateIE7" />
    <!--START: Adding of javaScript library -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!--END:   Adding of javaScript library-->
    <!--START: Adding of javaScript library need internet Connection-->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!--END: Adding of javaScript library need internet Connection-->
    <style>
    body{font-size:62.5%}
    div{font-size:100%}
    input.inputClass{font-size:1.2em;}

    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Container"><INPUT id=password class=inputClass title=Password  value="" size=39 type=password name=password /></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Fonts are shown differently depending on the browser's rendering engine. Chrome/Safari, Firefox, MSIE, and Opera use their own rendering engine, so actual font size would likely vary. You should use `em`, `ex`, or `pt` units when it comes to font size or its container and shouldn't be mixed with `px` unit.

Comment: @jay I am asking about the size of the password dots(masking character) which is showing as little tiny dots in webkit browsers but if you see the same dots in firefox and chrome, the masking character(dot) is bigger than webkit browsers' dot size, in all the browsers i have applied the same font size.for text boxes and all font-size is working correctly in all the browsers including webkit.

Comment: The latest HTML standard doesn't require password field characters to be displayed with a specific character. While HTML3.2 standard does mention that it *should* be displayed with characters like `*`, it doesn't require to be that specific characters. So it's up to the web browser to choose. As you can see, neither of them use `*` characters. They use *Bullet* or *Black Circle* character instead. Changing the font won't work since both characters will always be different.

Comment: @Jay My doubt is why there is no uniformity in the black dot's size for password in webkit and IE and FF(FF and IE behave similarly).In Webkit alone the black dot size is so small..

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Styling Password Fields in CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859727/styling-password-fields-in-css)