# Input password font -family

Tags: css

Is there a way to change the font of an `input["password"]`?

I've created a webfont (`WOFF`) with a `squared asterisk` to simulate `-webkit-text-security: squared`.

The font is rendered fine, I've tried in some `<h1>` and `<p>` but I'm unable to render that font on my `input[type="password"]`:

```
input[type="password"] {
  font-family: "Squared";  
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

Tried other font's but it seems I can't change the font that the browser sets for password inputs.

Is there any way to accomplish this?

I tried also with `!important`.

**UPDATE:** [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859727/styling-password-fields-in-css) provides answers involving fonts on passwords inputs. Is it failing just to me?

Comment: Still messing with this huh? I have an alternative idea if you'd like to try it. It involves javascript and overlaying 2 inputs.

Comment: Yeah, I guess I won't give up :) I'll love to hear the idea...

Comment: You could use a plain old `type="text"` input and then it would properly render your font.

Comment: @Jrod That was one option, and using javascript to render asterisks but I read about all the security issues it implies. I should'nt trade security for this feature

Comment: @WesleyMurch: jQuery is fine. Thanks in advance

Comment: @WesleyMurch: Sure, take your time! And I'll definitely need to rest after this endless fight with password inputs :)

Comment: @jviotti: Sorry I give up, my idea turned out to be more complicated than I anticipated. Here's where I stopped: http://jsfiddle.net/FdBR2/

Comment: @WesleyMurch Happens often... Don't worry, thanks a lot anyway

Comment: @jviotti Do you happen to have any links to articles detailing these security issues?  I'd love to read it as I have always assumed the only thing separating a password and regular textbox was the character masking.

Comment: @Jrod There was a discussion about this here at stackoverlow. I don't know much about security but it was something that involved XSS and the fact that browser treated password inputs differently. I'll try to find it

Comment: @WesleyMurch: If you are still interested, Ive developed a jQuery Solution: https://github.com/jviotti/jquery-squared-passwords

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is dependent upon the browser and possibly OS ..

You can use other properties but there isn't much you can do related to font-family without using JS ..

Comment: I guess I need to find a JS workaroud. I tried webfonts as I read somewhere a bunch of hours ago that a guy did it this way...

Comment: Sure, I'll be looking forward to your reponse. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the font through in a full declaration, rather than simply `font-family`:

```
input[type="password"] {
    font: "Squared";
    font-size: 18px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

Comment: Nothing. the curious thing is that It lets me modify font-size, letter-spacing,etc.. but no font

Comment: It could be a security 'feature' of browsers then... Sorry I can't help more.