# Changing input type='submit' font-family

Tags: css, fonts

I realize this sounds absurd, but I'm unable to change the font-family for an input type=submit button.

I've tried referencing it by id and input[type=submit], adding a !important tag in the css, and changing it in the dev tools, but nothing works. However, other css attributes are working (such as width, margins, etc).

Is there a css solution I'm overlooking here or should I change paths and style through jquery?

codepen:
http://codepen.io/blakeface/pen/mEJWQj?editors=1100

```
#submit-button {
  font-family: cursive;
  font-size: 10em;
  margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Similar question:
[Input password font -family](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13826132/input-password-font-family)

Comment: your codepen example worked for me.

Comment: it is working fine here. what OS/ browser are you using?

Comment: @dippas good point. I'm using Chrome. I'll experiment with another browser though.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you are looking for something more like [this](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BzNRBe?editors=1100)?
        `font-family: Vivaldi;`
 The 'cursive' font family for HTML/CSS isn't like conventional cursive handwriting. Your code works and displays 'cursive' font.

Comment: Thanks. I'm impartial to the cursive font-family. The goal here is to see a change in the font, which has been unsuccessful for me. I appreciate the comment though.

Comment: Where "this" means `font-family: Vivaldi;`?  We frown on link only answers.

Comment: Actually "this" was referring to how the button looks with Vivaldi, which I showed with a codepen. I decided to include the snippet of code that caused this change so that it wouldn't be a link-only answer.