# How can I style a html password field? Replace the default dots with something custom

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble styling a password field. I only need to know how can i replace the default dots with a custom image,like in the image below.

[image: http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/27/passworddots.png/]

Comment: You can't with pure CSS.

Comment: You might as well make a `<div>` and make it editable. Followed by that catch the keystrokes done inside that `<div>` with JavaScript (jQuery) and trigger to draw images inside them (with a string stored buffer for the password) and you have your custom input field :)

Answer (score 2):

Check [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859727/styling-password-fields-in-css). I found there something curious :)

```
input[type="password"]
{
  -webkit-text-security: disc;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. Webkit provides only few symbols, but you cannot define your own using it :(

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that with CSS. You'll need to make a custom control.

One way to do that would be to make a custom font where every character is the same glyph.
Another would be to use JS to capture the keyup events, then produce a div with a repeating background image.

(If you don't know how to do those, I'd just leave it as is – it's not a particularly straightforward task if you are a beginner.)

Answer (score 0):

> how can i replace the default dots with a custom image

You can't cross-browser with pure CSS. You could try to build a custom password field using JavaScript and a lot of event handlers, but it would inevitably have issues in one browser or another, especially for mobile devices which may use a different design or custom interaction for password fields.

Leave it alone, use the default text, and try to avoid messing with user expectations.