# HTML input type visible password

Tags: android, ios, html, cordova

my question is to make an input tag of type `password`, into an input type like `visible-password`.

I don't mean the type `text`, but a type password with the css rule like this:

```
-webkit-text-security: none !important;
```

but it doesn't work in my test.

Thanks to all

**EDIT:**

I want to use the "type's password" facilitation, like "no auto capitalize", or "no suggestion", without hiding the text. (the scenario is a cordova application, or touch screen devices). The type text (without any attributes) doesn't give this facilitations

Comment: Please refer to similar post here:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859727/styling-password-fields-in-css

Comment: yes, I had already read this post, but is not what I need. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solvet it, for my personal needed:

Im going to describe it, now i use:

```
<input id="my_id" type="text" autocomplete="off" autocapitalize="off" autocorrect="off"/>
```

using this HTML5 attributes

Comment: Does'nt that contradict "I don't mean the type text"?

Comment: I want to use the "type's password" facilitation, like "no auto capitalize", or "no suggestion", without hiding the text. (the scenario is a cordova application, or touch screen devices).
The type text (without any attributes) doesn't give this facilitations. Probably my question was placed incorrectly.