# How to mask characters entered in a text input without failing model validation?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, html, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

How do you emulate the behavior of the password field without using @Html.PasswordFor. In other words, I want to keep it as a text field (@Html.EditorFor), but show a masked character (*) instead of the typed-in character. The reason I don't want to use a password field is because this is not actually for a password, but for some other sensitive data, and using a password field means Chrome prompts the user to save the password.

I know I could use a javascript using onkeyup to convert the typed-in character to a masked character and save the actual character in a hidden field, but the problem is that the model validation on this field would reject that character.

What is the best way to approach this problem?

View

```
 @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Salary)
```

Model

```
[RegularExpression("([1-9][0-9]*)")] //model validation would reject asterisks.
public string Salary { get; set; }
```

Comment: Have you tried <input type="password">?

Comment: @Blue, Yes, as mentioned on the first line of the question. Html.PasswordFor is basically <input type=password>

Comment: You can try making it a text input and changing the font language to look like a password using css. It depends on what fonts you have available but is more maintainable/responsive than js to do it. Check this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6859727/styling-password-fields-in-css.

Comment: @Blue, Ok, I think something like that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a password field with autocomplete="off".

See [Chrome Browser Ignoring AutoComplete=Off](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12374442/chrome-browser-ignoring-autocomplete-off) and [Disable browser 'Save Password' functionality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32369/disable-browser-save-password-functionality).