# Change default password display to some other symbol in Form

Tags: html

In my form on my password input Instead of

```
*******
```

i want to display some other symbol say

```
########
```

when user inputs in it is it possible ?

Comment: Why would you do that? Do you _want_ to confuse your users?

Comment: Browser support? It's certainly possible in webkit browsers like Chrome and Safari but in other browsers you'd have to use JavaScript to simulate this behavior with an input text field, a hidden field and listening to key up and key down events.

Comment: Just to be different..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Changing the symbols shown of a HTML password field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648665/changing-the-symbols-shown-of-a-html-password-field)

Comment: You could, potentially, use the [`text-security` property](http://css-infos.net/property/-webkit-text-security), but this seems to be Webkit-only, and is limited to specific glyphs, rather than arbitrary characters.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on the user-agent (the browser) and is not changeable. What you *could* do is to use some JavaScript/[CSS](http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/) trick to imitate a [password input](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.password.html) using a [text input](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.text.html) and using `#`s instead of `*`s but I don't recommend it at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN"   "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<title>test</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
<script type="text/javascript">
var k=0;
var df;
window.onload=function() {
df=document.forms[0];
df[1].onkeyup=function() {
df[0].value+=df[1].value.charAt(k);
k++;
for(c=0;c<df[1].value.length;c++) {
df[1].value=df[1].value.replace(df[1].value.charAt(c),'#');
 }
 }
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
<noscript><div>Without javascript enabled you will be unable to login</div></noscript>
<form action="http://www.google.com/">
<div>
<input type="hidden" name="password">
<input type="text">
<input type="submit" value="submit password">
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For your answer to be helpful you could add some explanation or comments. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer