# Replace text with stars (*) in html with directives in angularjs

Tags: html, angularjs, input, angularjs-directive, passwords

I need a textarea control with mask able property, if the textarea is mask able then the text should appear as stars instead of actual text.

I can have any no of textareas in my form, So i can't save actual text in other variable and save the stars or dots for actual textarea.

Can somebody help me to solve this issue?

Comment: "*without javascript*"? not possible.

Comment: See this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648665/changing-the-symbols-shown-of-a-html-password-field

Comment: If you had check at this [StackOverflow Question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648665/changing-the-symbols-shown-of-a-html-password-field) you would understand that without JavaScript it is quite impossible ! **EDIT** Was too late ! @OSDM

Comment: What's wrong with dots?

Comment: Our client asked me to do a mask able textbox, and if hide input property set to true for any form input control,  the entered text should be (* 's)

Comment: Dots have been the standard UI for masking input for years now. Sometimes it's easier to talk back to a client and explain that rather than bending over backwards and trying to adhere to every minute request.

Answer (score 3):

**As others have already pointed out, it's not possible and should not be done**. But here is something which you should give a try. If you really want to achieve it, you'll have to compromise on something. Use `contenteditable` div instead of input and use following CSS:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/GCu2D/793/

CSS:

```
.checked {
    font-size:20px;
    position:relative;
    display:inline-block;
    border:1px solid red;
}
.checked:before {
    font-size: inherit;
    content:" ";
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: #FFF;
    width: 100%;
    background-image: url("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/b/b5/Asterisk.svg/32px-Asterisk.svg.png");
    background-repeat: repeat-x;
    z-index: 1;
    background-size: 12px;
    background-position: left center;
}
```

**HTML**:

```
<div contenteditable class="checked">Sample Text</div>
```

Obviously, this is not a perfect solution, but you can start from here.

**Note:** You will need to adjust the font-size and the image used. Both dimensions needs to be in sync. Ofcourse you can change the size of image using `background-size` . Border here is just for visual feedback. If you need to adjust the width of the stars, then you may use `calc()` and play around with the exact dimension.

Comment: This https://medium.com/@wowmotty/replace-the-input-password-bullet-1cd4ee34e0aa and this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45956661/adding-fontello-in-angular-cli