# Adding fontello in angular cli

Tags: angular, fontello

I want use in AngularCLI project one icon from fontello so I installed in npm:
npm install --save fontello-cli

Result:
New folder in node_modules so it's good but I don't see some css file. So how can I add some icon into my project without css file?
When I installed font-awesome, there is css file so I know how I can add this into my project.

Comment: make use of `angular-cli.json` file add it in the `styles array`

Comment: But like I told, I dont have css file so how can I add path to `styles array`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put all the created files and folders inside the assets folder.
Then add the following entry in the styles array inside .angular-cli.json :

```
"assets/css/fontello.css"
```

PS : I used http://fontello.com to create the two icons I used in my angular project

Comment: GREAT! Works like charm!