# how to change password dots to to Asterisk

Tags: html, css

I am creating the password field, and I have to use Asterisk in place of password dots. currently, I am using this

```
<input type="text" style="-webkit-text-security: square;" />
```

but when I use Asterisk in place of the square then it's not working. Is there any solution for that.

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify `password` in your input's type field.
Like this:

```
<input type="password" style="-webkit-text-security: square;" />
```

See here for more information: https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_input_types.asp

---

You might also want to see:

- this answer: [Changing the symbols shown of a HTML password field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648665/changing-the-symbols-shown-of-a-html-password-field/1648690#1648690)
- and this answer: [Replace text with stars (*) in html with directives in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31604402/replace-text-with-stars-in-html-with-directives-in-angularjs?noredirect=1#comment51159417_31604402)

Comment: but I need asterisks in place of dots. how it can be possible

Comment: You might want to see this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1648690/4603295

And this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31604402/replace-text-with-stars-in-html-with-directives-in-angularjs?noredirect=1#comment51159417_31604402