# how to make a displayformat (*) in textbox in asp.net

Tags: html, asp.net, vb.net

i wanted to make a Login page, but i dont know how to make a displayformat in password textbox. I want to display (*) whenever i started to type in the password textbox in ASP.NET .

here is my code:

```
<form method="post" action="" runat="server">
    <p><asp:TextBox id="txtUser" runat="server" placeholder="Username"/></p>
    <p><asp:TextBox id="txtPass" runat="server" placeholder="Password"/></p>
    <p class = "remember_me">
    <label>
    <label>
    <input type = "checkbox" name = "remember_me" id = "remember_me" runat="server">
    Remember me on this computer
    </label>
    </label>
    </p>
    <p class="submit"><asp:Button id="btnLogin" Text="Login" runat="server" OnClick="submit" /></p>
</form>
```

Comment: doesn't it automatically show masking character `(•)`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing the symbols shown of a HTML password field](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648665/changing-the-symbols-shown-of-a-html-password-field)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use input type *password* for html. 
e.g.

```
 <input type="password" name="psw">
```

For ASP.NET

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtBox1" TextMode="Password" runat="server" />
```