# change password input from bullet points to squares

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm creating a simple login form on my site. Most of the login page has a very "square" look to it, except for the password input which uses little circles.

I would like to continue on the "square" look into the password input, however, there doesn't seem to be any solutions I can find.

Assuming this is my current input field in my HTML, how would I use CSS to turn the circles to squares in my password field?

```
<input type="password" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="off">
```

I have seen this effect on other websites that I have visited, but I can't manage to duplicate the square inputs. If there is no way to do this in CSS, would it be possible to do it in JavaScript?

Thanks. :)

Comment: It's actually discouraged to change this. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648665/changing-the-symbols-shown-of-a-html-password-field

Comment: @Kerstomaat already seen it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how well is this supported, so it's always a good practice to check for support and change input type if CSS is not supported

```js
window.onload = function() {
  init();
}

function init() {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("sqpass")[0];
  var style = window.getComputedStyle(x);
  if (!style.webkitTextSecurity && !style.textSecurity) {
    x.setAttribute("type", "password");
  }
}
```

```css
input.sqpass {
  -webkit-text-security: square;
  text-security: square;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" name="password" id="password" autocomplete="off" class="sqpass">
```

Comment: I think it's currently supported only by webkit browsers, but I've added text-security just to be sure and also condition in JS to check textSecurity (if it doesn't exist, it will throw false anyways)

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble due to there being more than 1 input field on the page... Is there a way to use the `getElementByID` function instead? Thanks

Comment: oh, sure .. changed to `getElementsByClassName('sqpass')[0]` .. should be fine - it can work for password + confirm password for example