# Exactly which utf-8 character is being used to represent the chars in a password input string?

Tags: html, utf-8, passwords, ethereum

For some strange reason the private key of my ethereum wallet has been encrypted with a string different from the one I thought I had copied and pasted into the password field. So I'm currently in a quest to recover my wallet.

One possibility is that I may have unknowingly copied and pasted a string of bullet-like symbols (•) into the password field, thinking that it was something else. But I am not sure exactly which utf-8 character this bullet-like symbol is.

Does anyone know if there is a standard for the utf-8 character being used to display the chars in a password input string in `<input type="password">`?

[image]

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648665/changing-the-symbols-shown-of-a-html-password-field (But this post mentioned nothing about the standard for the utf-8 character being used in password fields)

Comment: Password edit controls usually do not let you copy their content, so I wonder how you would have got the bullets into the clipboard.

Comment: @martinstoeckli I have no idea mate. But I recall at one point I was fiddling with the `show password` button. And if I remembered correctly I saw a string of bullets being displayed even though `show password` was on. At that time I thought it could just be a GUI bug but now that I'm not able to decrypt my private key I'm just exploring all the possibilities.

Comment: Is it possible that you thought you copied the password from the password-box, but because the password-box don't let you copy the content, you pasted the content which was active in the clipboard at this time?

Comment: Two possible candidates for bullets are • and • [maybe there are others](http://www.martinstoeckli.ch/fontmap/fontmap.html).

Comment: @martinstoeckli yeah I'm exploring that possibility too. But unfortunately I don't have access to the history of my clipboard.. So I am trying very hard to remember what I copied before that.

Comment: @martinstoeckli that link is super helpful. Thanks mate!