# how to Mask password like excel in php

Tags: javascript, php, html, passwords, mask

I have been using excel sheet all this while to store my passwords like below

[image]

we are moving all the excel data to MySQL database. I need to mask the password just like how I have been doing it in excel using PHP. Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Is it encryption password?

Comment: Are you asking how to use random symbols instead of dots, or are you trying to encrypt your password this way?

Comment: yes, i achieve with the format cells -> Font ->wingdings and password is encrypted. The same need to be achieved in webpage and when i copy and paste it elsewhere form the webpage, it should return the actual password. Is this possible?

Comment: _...and password is encrypted_ And you don't think that anybody else would read your password very easily that way? You are not using any crypto but just changing the font---

Comment: This is for internal use, we don't want somebody to shoulder surf thats all.

Comment: Sorry, you are contradicting yourself. Is internal not that important? Then why hiding? Is it important? Then why not using standards? Have fun

Comment: People who have access, will be able to access it.we do not want some body to SHOULDER SURF. Thats all. I hope you got it. Will not be asking a question if its not important. Thank you Bub

Comment: I got it guys. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

You cannot change HTML's masking technic for passwords or even if you do, by using another input, it won't provide the same security as a password field. Check [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648665/changing-the-symbols-shown-of-a-html-password-field) for more information.
Now, if you're asking if you could encrypt your passwords in your MySQL database, there is a large variety of encrypting technologies such as sha1 and md5. Check [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/encryption-functions.html)for more information into password encryption.