# How to show div next to password input field?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to show password verification box next to input field. This logic works but Box with all password requirements isn't showing in the right position. Instead of being positioned next to the field it's showing over the field. Here is example:

```js
$('input[type=password]').keyup(function() {
 var pswd = $(this).val();
 
    //validate the length
 if ( pswd.length < 8 ) {
     $('#length').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
 } else {
     $('#length').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
 }

    //validate letter
 if ( pswd.match(/[A-z]/) ) {
     $('#letter').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
 } else {
     $('#letter').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
 }

 //validate capital letter
 if ( pswd.match(/[A-Z]/) ) {
     $('#capital').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
 } else {
     $('#capital').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
 }

 //validate number
 if ( pswd.match(/\d/) ) {
     $('#number').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
 } else {
     $('#number').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
 }
}).focus(function() {
    $('#pswd_info').show();
}).blur(function() {
    $('#pswd_info').hide();
});
```

```css
.form-group.required .control-label:after {
   content: "*";
   color: red;
}
#pswd_info {
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-75px;
    bottom: -115px\9; /* IE Specific */
    right:55px;
    width:250px;
    padding:15px;
    background:#fefefe;
    font-size:.875em;
    border-radius:5px;
    box-shadow:0 1px 3px #ccc;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
}
#pswd_info h4 {
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
    padding:0;
    font-weight:normal;
}
#pswd_info::before {
    content: "\25B2";
    position:absolute;
    top:-12px;
    left:45%;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:14px;
    color:#ddd;
    text-shadow:none;
    display:block;
}
.invalid {
    background:url(../images/invalid.png) no-repeat 0 50%;
    padding-left:22px;
    line-height:24px;
    color:#ec3f41;
}
.valid {
    background:url(../images/valid.png) no-repeat 0 50%;
    padding-left:22px;
    line-height:24px;
    color:#3a7d34;
}
#pswd_info {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group required">
      <label class="control-label" for="fname">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="temp_fname" id="temp_fname" placeholder="Enter First Name" maxlength="50" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required">
      <label class="control-label" for="lname">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="temp_lname" id="temp_lname" placeholder="Enter Last Name" maxlength="50" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required">
      <label class="control-label" for="username">UserName</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="temp_username" id="temp_username" placeholder="Enter UserName" maxlength="50" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required">
      <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="temp_password" id="temp_password" placeholder="Enter Password" maxlength="64" required>
      <small id="passwordHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Special characters are allowd:  <span class="text-danger">!"#$%&'()*+,-.:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~</span></small>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required">
      <label class="control-label" for="email">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="temp_email" id="temp_email" placeholder="Enter email" maxlength="80" required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
<div id="pswd_info">
  <h4>Password must meet the following requirements:</h4>
  <ul>
    <li id="letter" class="invalid">At least <strong>one letter</strong></li>
    <li id="capital" class="invalid">At least <strong>one capital letter</strong></li>
    <li id="number" class="invalid">At least <strong>one number</strong></li>
    <li id="length" class="invalid">Be at least <strong>8 characters</strong></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Is there a way to show password box next to Password input field? Also can arrow on the box point from the left side of the box if the box is on the right hand side from the input field? There is problem with images that should replace bullets. I'm not sure why but bullet and image are displayed. Only image should be in there. if anyone see why my code is breaking please let me know.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```js
$('input[type=password]').keyup(function() {
 var pswd = $(this).val();
 
    //validate the length
 if ( pswd.length < 8 ) {
     $('#length').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
 } else {
     $('#length').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
 }

    //validate letter
 if ( pswd.match(/[A-z]/) ) {
     $('#letter').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
 } else {
     $('#letter').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
 }

 //validate capital letter
 if ( pswd.match(/[A-Z]/) ) {
     $('#capital').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
 } else {
     $('#capital').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
 }

 //validate number
 if ( pswd.match(/\d/) ) {
     $('#number').removeClass('invalid').addClass('valid');
 } else {
     $('#number').removeClass('valid').addClass('invalid');
 }
}).focus(function() {
    $('#pswd_info').show();
}).blur(function() {
    $('#pswd_info').hide();
});
```

```css
.form-group.required .control-label:after {
   content: "*";
   color: red;
}

.password-container {
  position: relative;
}
#pswd_info {
    position:absolute;
    top: 85px;
    left: 25px;
    width:250px;
    padding:15px;
    background:#fefefe;
    font-size:.875em;
    border-radius:5px;
    box-shadow:0 1px 3px #ccc;
    border:1px solid #ddd;
}
#pswd_info h4 {
    margin:0 0 10px 0;
    padding:0;
    font-weight:normal;
}
#pswd_info::before {
    content: "\25B2";
    position:absolute;
    top:-12px;
    left:45%;
    font-size:14px;
    line-height:14px;
    color:#ddd;
    text-shadow:none;
    display:block;
}
.invalid {
    background:url(../images/invalid.png) no-repeat 0 50%;
    padding-left:22px;
    line-height:24px;
    color:#ec3f41;
}
.valid {
    background:url(../images/valid.png) no-repeat 0 50%;
    padding-left:22px;
    line-height:24px;
    color:#3a7d34;
}
#pswd_info {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

<div class="container">
  <form>
    <div class="form-group required">
      <label class="control-label" for="fname">First Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="temp_fname" id="temp_fname" placeholder="Enter First Name" maxlength="50" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required">
      <label class="control-label" for="lname">Last Name</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="temp_lname" id="temp_lname" placeholder="Enter Last Name" maxlength="50" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required">
      <label class="control-label" for="username">UserName</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="temp_username" id="temp_username" placeholder="Enter UserName" maxlength="50" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required password-container">
      <label class="control-label" for="password">Password</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="temp_password" id="temp_password" placeholder="Enter Password" maxlength="64" required>
      <small id="passwordHelp" class="form-text text-muted">Special characters are allowd:  <span class="text-danger">!"#$%&'()*+,-.:;<=>?@[\]^_`{|}~</span></small>
      <div id="pswd_info">
        <h4>Password must meet the following requirements:</h4>
        <ul>
          <li id="letter" class="invalid">At least <strong>one letter</strong></li>
          <li id="capital" class="invalid">At least <strong>one capital letter</strong></li>
          <li id="number" class="invalid">At least <strong>one number</strong></li>
          <li id="length" class="invalid">Be at least <strong>8 characters</strong></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group required">
      <label class="control-label" for="email">Email address</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="temp_email" id="temp_email" placeholder="Enter email" maxlength="80" required>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
```

- I moved the location of your popup to be within the block that holds the password.
- I set the `position` of the containing block to relative. This allows the children to be positioned relative to this block without moving the block
- I changed the CSS to position based on the new parent block

Comment: Works now and box is showing below password input field but still bullet is showing instead of an image. Is there a way to show image only and remove the bullet in verification box?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648665/changing-the-symbols-shown-of-a-html-password-field

Comment: I'm not talking about mask password bullet. Div window where li elements have image valid/invalid should replace bullets.

Comment: can't you just add <ul style="list-style: none;"> to the above css to remove bullets

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. Either do what @iceveda06 says or just don't use the `<ul>`

Comment: @Intervalia What would be the best solution to place pswd_info div on the right side next to input password field? I'm wondering if that would work on all screen sizes?

Comment: There is some pretty tricky math that needs to happen to determine if the popup can show next to the input field vs. below it. You need to see if it will fit and, if not change it to the other position. You would also need an arrow on the side vs an arrow on the top.