# React-Native: How to either a) clear a text input or b) disable the text that is typed from being displayed

Tags: reactjs, react-native, input

I am trying to create a way for the user to type in a five digit numeric code. The problem is that I want whatever number they type in to be transformed into an astrice. My first attempt was to set the `value` to display text but that did absolutely nothing. So then, I decided to  make a text component who's text is the transformed text and then to just make the text input text transparent. This is obviously far from ideal but it gets the job. Ideally I would like some way of either

a) having and input box that doesn't actually display input letting my text component handle the display

b) have a way to clear the text in the input (less ideal but at least this would prevent having long transparent strings in the background)

c) someone offer me new approach altogether and tell me im an idiot for even trying to do it this way.

generateDisplayText is responsible for transforming current input based on astrices. It just uses the length of the current input to determine how many astrices and underscores to show.

onPress updates the state of current input so far

onChange calls check match which checks if there is a match

[image]

```
import React from 'react';
import {Button} from 'react-native-elements';
import ScreenNames from './ScreenNames';
import {Common, Colors, Sizes} from '../themes/Styles';
import {View, TextInput, Text} from 'react-native';
import Base from './Base';

const CODE_LENGTH = 5;
const MATCH = false;
const INITIAL_STATE = {
    text: [],
    displayText: generateDisplayText(0),
    value: '',
};
function generateDisplayText(textLength) {
    let ret = '* '.repeat(textLength) + '_ '.repeat(CODE_LENGTH - textLength);
    return ret;
}

export default class Password extends Base {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = INITIAL_STATE;
    }
    componentDidMount() {
        this.refs.textInput.focus();
    }
    pressHandler = event => {
        let key = event.nativeEvent.key;
        key === 'Backspace'
            ? this.setState(oldState => ({text: oldState.text.slice(0, -1)}))
            : this.setState(oldState => ({text: oldState.text.concat(key)}));
        this.setState(oldState => ({
            displayText: generateDisplayText(oldState.text.length),
        }));
    };
    checkForMatch = () => {
        if (this.state.text.length >= CODE_LENGTH) {
            if (MATCH) {
                //go to next screen
                //
            }
            this.refs.textInput.clearImmediate();
            this.setState(() => INITIAL_STATE);

        }
    };
    render() {
        return (
            <View
                style={{
                    flex: 1,
                    width: '100%',
                    height: '100%',
                    marginTop: 20,
                }}>
                <View
                    justification="center"
                    alignment="center"
                    style={{
                        justifyContent: 'center',
                        alignItems: 'center',
                        flex: 1,
                        marginTop: 10,
                    }}>
                    <TextInput
                        style={{fontSize: 20, color: 'green'}}
                        selectionColor="transparent"
                        ref="textInput"
                        placeholderTextColor="black"
                        keyboardType="number-pad"
                        sectureTextEntry={true}
                        onKeyPress={this.pressHandler}
                        onChange={this.checkForMatch}
                        autoCorrect={false}
                        onChangeText={text => this.setState({value: text})}
                        value={this.state.value}
                    />
                    <Text style={{fontSize: 60}}>
                        {' '}
                        {this.state.displayText}{' '}
                    </Text>
                </View>
            </View>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648665/changing-the-symbols-shown-of-a-html-password-field

Comment: Seems to be generally frowned upon, if this is being used for something that needs to remain secure.

Comment: ok, any suggestions as far out of the box components to achieve this purpose? Maybe a form?

Comment: Like a poster in the link says, you can substitute each character with an asterisk as the user types, but the thing is it is not a good idea to roll your own security. If you're not set on the asterisks, you can just add 'type="password"' to the input, and that will do it.