# How can i mask a span character same as input type password using css

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I wanted to mask a span character same as input type password using `css`.

Is there any properties `type="password"` for the span or something or any class present in bootstrap e.g. `class="mask"` or something.

[image]

[image]

I don't want to edit my `HTML`, so I can't replace span with `input type="password"`
Please help.

Comment: But it is still some listener which receives keyboard input?

Comment: Thanks for comment @A.Larsson I just wanted to use the CSS property for masking the character. This will help me.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to edit your HTML to replace the span to a proper input type="password"? What you are trying to achieve is a bad practice, but if you MUST do it, i'll say use the suggestion that @annz left below.

Comment: I tried @annz solution but it's not working in IE and mozilla

Answer (score 1):

Please use the style

`.mask{ -webkit-text-security: disc !important; }`

Comment: it's not working in Mozilla and IE after adding browser prefix as well.

Comment: You can't change the password masking character in the standard password field. You can fake it with a textbox, but it makes for a weak security.

Comment: please search the post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648665/changing-the-symbols-shown-of-a-html-password-field

Answer (score 0):

You can use

`span {color: transparent}`

and after that style the pseudo selector :before/:after

`span:before {position: absolute; width: 100%; height: 100%; content: '***'}`

But if you want to make * to be equal the letter quantity, I think you need to use javascript

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I will check this.