# How to save user input in another variable

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to mask password with asterisk in javascript and not using the `type="password"` because it is not asterisks. So I save the password in a variable and then make a new variable for replacing the password with asterisk(*). After that I tried to pass the `var y` to another `get()` function for password condition. The problem is it seems like the `var y` is not passed to `get()` function.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>A function is triggered when the user releases a key in the input field. The function transforms the character to upper case.</p>
Enter your name: <input type="text" id="pass" onkeyup="myFunction()">

<button onclick="get()">get password</button>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  var y = document.getElementById("pass");
  get(y);
  var x = document.getElementById("pass");
  x.value = x.value.replace(/./gi, '*');
}

function get(y){ 
  var pass = y;
  document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = pass;
}
</script>
<p id="p"></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: why you can't use the type password? I think it's the best way to do it, without reinventing the wheel

Comment: I wouldn't replace your password field with a text one because of the reasons stated here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1648690/2232127

Comment: If you don't mind me asking, why in particularly do you wish to use asterisks instead of the standard filled circles from `type=password`?

Comment: Please, use the regular password type. `type=password`

Comment: Because I want to learn how to mask input in javascript.

Comment: There's reasons there's a password field type--ignore at your app's security's peril. What you're doing is a bad idea.

Comment: @DaveNewton Please do share your if you have any better idea on how to mask the input with asterisk in javascript?

Comment: Masking with an asterisk is trivial. The point is that for security purposes it's a terrible idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This script should work, i just declare "pass" as global variable so you can store value inside and don't lose it when function ends

```
var pass ="";
function myFunction() {
  var y = document.getElementById("pass");
  get(y);
  var x = document.getElementById("pass");
  x.value = x.value.replace(/./gi, '*');
}

function get(y){    
  pass += y.value[y.value.length -1];
  document.getElementById("p").innerHTML = pass;
}
```

## update 1

```
pass += y.value[y.value.length -1];
```

is equal to `pass = pass + y.value[y.value.length -1];` so if you have already insert "123" and you want to insert "4" this line will do `pass = "123" + y.value[y.value.length -1];`
now let's speak about `y.value[y.value.length -1];` y.value is the value inside your  and y.value.lenght is the lenght of your string (string is an array of characters) so if you got "***4" inside your  tag `y.value.length` is equal to 4.
In javascript and in most of other languages you can pick single characters from strings like you do with arrays. See example below

```
var text = "abcd";
text[0] // "a"
text[1] // "b"
text[2] // "c"
text[3]+text[0]// "da"
```

so if we have `y.value = "***4"` and `y.value.length = 4` you have to subtract 1 because array start from 0 and if you do `y.value[y.value.length -1]` you will take the last character. So

```
//pass = "123"
//i insert "4"
pass += y.value[y.value.length -1]; // pass = "123" + "4"
//pass = "1234"
```

Comment: But i'm not shure if mask password like that is a good idea, if you want protect your clients you have to think about ecryption of your password and MITM prevention

Comment: I guess this is the basic for us to learn as a beginner in javascript. Could you explain what does this line do `pass += y.value[y.value.length -1];` .

Comment: Okay thanks! I get it now but I noticed that when I type it quickly the output is different that it suddenly include additional asterisks and if I erased the one that I just typed it still store the value. Why is that happening? is it because I am using `onkeyup` ?

Comment: yes, try to use `onkeypress` and `setTimeout(function,milliseconds)` to delay execution by 1-2 milliseconds and you should implement some check by character inside get() function

Answer (score 0):

```
         var y = document.getElementById("pass").value;
```

use this to pass value but whenever you click button it will replace with star as you are using one onclick function also and to over come just check if on click input value is star don't update your variable