# How to create custom font face to use font awesome's asterisk icon

Tags: html, css, font-awesome, font-face

Actually my requirement is to display asterisk in place of dots in input type password. I am trying to replace the dot icon in the default input type password to '*'. I am using a font face rule in order to do this. But Struck how to add URLs for **Asterisk** icon in font awesome. Could anyone please help me out with this?

Below is my code.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./demo.css">
  <style>
    @font-face {
      font-family: 'Asterisk';
      src: url('./star-of-life-solid');
      //How can I add URL here ??????? is my question
      src: url('./star-of-life-solid.svg') format('svg'), url('./star-of-life-solid.png') format('png');
      /*url('./font/fontello.eot?13442593#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
                             url('./font/fontello.woff2?13442593') format('woff2'),
                             url('./font/fontello.woff?13442593') format('woff'),
                             url('./font/fontello.ttf?13442593') format('truetype');*/
      font-weight: normal;
      font-style: normal;
    }
    
    input[type="password"] {
      font-family: "Asterisk";
      font-style: normal;
      font-weight: normal;
      speak: none;
      color: red;
      /* For safety - reset parent styles, that can break glyph codes*/
      font-variant: normal;
      text-transform: none;
      /* Font smoothing. That was taken from TWBS */
      -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
      -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
      /* Uncomment for 3D effect */
      /* text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(127, 127, 127, 0.3); */
      /* add spacing to better separate each image */
      letter-spacing: 2px;
    }
  </style>

</head>

<body>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      Type in the password input: //Using input type password. But want to display Asterisk in place of dots which is by default.
      <input type="password">
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to change default browser behaviour?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Changing the symbols shown in a HTML password field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1648665/changing-the-symbols-shown-in-a-html-password-field)

Comment: The answer is here
You shouldn't change it https://stackoverflow.com/a/1648690/14032651